# How to update a matrix with another Matrix using Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

```
void Visual_Servoing::Pose_callback(const   geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr &msg) 
{
    this->hole_detection(frame);
    this->generate_line();
    iterator = iterator + 1;
    QuatX = msg->pose.orientation.x;
    QuatY = msg->pose.orientation.y;
    QuatZ = msg->pose.orientation.z;
    QuatW = msg->pose.orientation.w;  
    Rotation << (1 - (2*pow(QuatY,2)) - (2*pow(QuatZ,2))), (2*QuatX*QuatY + 2*QuatW*QuatZ)   , (2*QuatX*QuatZ - 2*QuatW*QuatY),
                (2*QuatX*QuatY - 2*QuatW*QuatZ)  , (1 - (2*pow(QuatX,2)) - (2*pow(QuatZ,2))) , (2*QuatY*QuatZ + 2*QuatW*QuatX),
                (2*QuatX*QuatZ + 2*QuatW*QuatY)  , (2*QuatY*QuatZ - 2*QuatW*QuatX)   , (1 - (2*pow(QuatX,2)) - (2*pow(QuatY,2))); 
    

for ( int i=0; i<10: i++)
   {
       Rotations.col(i) = Rotation; //This part is not valid
    }

    if (iterator>10)
    {   
        CirclePosinFrame();
        CirclePoseIntertial();
        
        theta1.clear();
        theta2.clear();
        VectorCam.clear();
        VectorsCam.clear();
        iterator.clear();
    }

    
}
```

This is the code. Please note that I want to update Rotations Matrix by Rotation Matrix. Both are defined as a Eigen::Matrix3f Rotation;
and Eigen::MatrixXf Rotations;

Comment: Translation has to be in the for loop, by mistake

Comment: Maybe you just put the ```Eigen::MatrixXf Translations(3, 10);``` into the loop by mistake? It should be outside the loop, otherwise it will go out of scope once the loop ends. And otherwise, it should work. You can assign a vector to a column expression, that shouldn't be the issue.
As to how you access them, ```.col(i)``` already does that, so what's the question exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry I have a missing info in the code, the Question is, I want to have a matrix that is updating by adding a matrix "Rotation" to "Rotations" matrix and then access the rotation matrices
[Eigen::Matrix3f Rotation; // 3x3 Rotation Matrix 
Eigen::MatrixXf VecsinInertial]

Comment: Can you post that code? I don't really understand it from your comment, but I'm sure we can work it out.

Comment: I edited the main code, please check it, Thanks !

Comment: What dimensions does ```Rotations``` have? It's a ```MatrixXf```, so the size is not clear from the code. If it has the dimensions ```(3, 10)```, and you're trying to assign ten 3x3 matrices to it, that won't work, because 3x10 = 300 != 10 * 3x3 = 900.
I still don't really understand what you're trying to do. If ```Rotations``` is only supposed to collect all rotations, why not use a ```std::array<Eigen::Matrix3f, 10>``` instead?
Otherwise, with the correct size for ```Rotations```, you could use block assignment.

Comment: Please read how and why to provide a [mre] (this would save a lot of discussion).

Comment: Thank you very much RL-S, I used block assignmen as you suggested and its working, also, I used .resize() to update the rotations Matrix dimensions

Comment: Now I have another issue, .resize() doesit omit the already existing values in the matrix ? is their anyother way to upsate it the size and keep the elements inside ?

Comment: From the documentation: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a9fd0703bd7bfe89d6dc80e2ce87c312a
"If the current number of coefficients of *this exactly matches the product rows * cols, then no memory allocation is performed and the current values are left unchanged. In all other cases, including shrinking, the data is reallocated and all previous values are lost."
I very much suggest you consider using ```std::array<Matrix3f,10>``` (if it's always 10 matrices) or ```std::vector<Matrix3f>``` instead.

Comment: And please consider @chtz comment as well. An MRE would really help everyone understand your problem much better